# Getting and inserting into other table UserId

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, uniqueidentifier, userid

How can I get with C# logged in UserID **to insert it into other database table**?

Columns in second table has the same datatype (**uniqueidentifier**) as column UserId in aspnet_Membership table.

It doesn't work for me if I try to put value of Guid variable type and string:

```
(...)    
public MembershipUser mojObiekt = Membership.GetUser();
(...)
string userID = myObject.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
Guid userkGuid = new Guid(userID);
```

and convert function to uniqueidentifier in SQL query also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just convert the column in the other table to a string and insert the uniqueidentifier as a string in the other table.

Comment: Thank you. How many max number of chars should have this column?
Has UserId column fixed length?

Comment: 32 chars is not enough, I had to set CHAR (37) for this column.